# Is my computer good enough for Zorin OS?

Tags: zorin

I'm relatively new to Linux. I've checked out a few distros and installed a few. What are the requirements for Zorin and Zorin lite. I'm looking for it to be responsive, stable, and get relatively good performance and battery life. This is my school laptop so it is mostly just for internet searching and notetaking via Google Docs. I would like to use Zorin but if my computer's spec aren't good enough I want to go to Zorin Lite.

Answer (score 3):

Zorin publishes their [minimal system requirements online for all their versions including Lite](https://help.zorin.com/docs/getting-started/system-requirements/). And for Ubuntu Desktop-based derivatives you can usually check the upstream the [Ubuntu Desktop minimal system requirements in their wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

But, the best way of knowing if a version of Linux is going to run on computer is to create a Live USB for the distro and try to run it. If there's something in Zorin that attracts you, go for the route of the Live USB and give it a try.